# What prevents a negative value for $\Delta \tau ^2$ when using the non-rotating Schwarzschild metric as $r_s/r$ grows large?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

What prevents a negative value for $\Delta \tau ^2$  when using the non-rotating Schwarzschild metric as $r_s/r$ grows large?  Note:  I am highly likely to be misinterpreting something.  My understanding for non-rotating systems is that the proper time is related to our time $t$ in units of nanoseconds and our measure of distance $r$ in units of nanolightseconds is:

$\Delta \tau ^2 = (1-r_s/r)\Delta t^2 - \Delta r^2 /(1-r_s/r)$

But if $\Delta t$ = 1 nanosecond and $\Delta r$ = 0.5 nanolightseconds and $(1-r_s/r$) = 0.4, we end up with 0.4 - .25/.4 = a negative.

Comment: $\Delta \tau^2$ can be negative in Minkowski spacetime too;  pick $\Delta t < \Delta r$, and $\Delta \tau^2 = \Delta t^2 - \Delta r^2 < 0$.  Can you elaborate on why this bothers you in the Schwarzschild context and not in the Minkowski context?

Comment: I am used to such problems being like "an astronaut travels 1 lightyear in 2 years by our measure.  What is the proper time?"  Then $\Delta \tau = \sqrt{ \Delta t^2 - \Delta r^2}$ and there is never any problem because $\Delta r = v \Delta t/c$ and is always less than $\Delta t$ because velocity must be less than lightspeed.

Comment: But your analagous problem in Minkowski spacetime is that $\Delta t = 1$ ns and $\Delta r > 1$ ns, which would also result in a negative $\Delta \tau^2$. All you have shown is that it is impossible for a single observer to be present at both the spacetime points you have defined - i.e. they cannot be causally linked.

Comment: Thak you, but in Minkowski spacetime, I have no problem saying if $\Delta t$=1 ns, $\Delta r$ must be less than 1 because nothing can go as fast as lightspeed.  With the Schwarzschild metric, it appeared to me that you could have a negative $\Delta \tau^2$ while the object is still moving less than light speed.  I see in Claudio's response below, that for less than lightspeed velocity, $\Delta r$ is further constrained to be even smaller, and that is why the negative value never occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that nothing prevents two events separated by a particular $\Delta t$ and $\Delta r$ from having a spacetime separation $\Delta \tau^2 < 0$.  Two events that are separated by a spacetime interval for which $\Delta \tau^2 < 0$ are called *spacelike separated* events, and it means that no observer can be present at both of these events.

Note that you can do analogous calculations in Minkowski spacetime just as easily;  this feature is not unique to Schwarzschild.  For example, if we consider two events in Minkowski spacetime separated by $\Delta t = 0.1$ ns and $\Delta r = 0.5$ ns (in units where $c = 1$), then it's not hard to see that $\Delta \tau^2 =\Delta t^2 - \Delta r^2 < 0$ for these two events as well.  This simply means that no observer can be present at both of these events.

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta r$ and $\Delta t$ are parameters of the metric, not the actual distance and time measured by a local observer. If $\Delta t$ is set to $1$ns, the interval of time for an observer keeping the same $r$ is $\sqrt{0.4}$. On the other hand, the spacial distance (that is, for the same time) between points separated by  $\Delta r = 0.5$ is $\sqrt{\frac{0.25}{0.4}}$. Dividing them we get a speed greater than 1 (c), what is not locally possible.

Comment: Thank you!  I interprete this as follows:  My simplistic t=1 and r=0.5 is based on a velocity of half lightspeed, and r = 0.5t = 0.5.  But if the situation involves a gravity impact of $(1-r_s/r)$ = 0.4, then the local time speed is $\sqrt{0.4}$ so the distance to use  is  $v \Delta t/c *(1-r_s/r)^{.5}$ = 0.316 ns.  Then I see $\Delta \tau^2 =(1-r_s/r)(t^2-v^2t^2/c^2)$ will always be a positive value, since v<c always (this would apply to only short enough distances to approximate $r_s/r$ is constant).

Comment: yes, it is right.